# Difficult induced current problem

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

consider the following setup shown below in the diagram. A circular conducting ring is placed in a increasing magnetic field into the page.Points $A$ and $B$ contain two bulbs. Initially both are glowing.after some time the points $P$ and $Q$ are shorted using a conducting wire of negligible resistance connecting the two points $P$ and $Q$.which of the following can happen

1. both the bulbs get dimmer,
2. A gets brighter and B gets dimmer or
3. B gets brighter and A gets dimmer.

[image]

Comment: It's usually not advised to indicate the difficulty of a problem in the question title. What's difficult to some may be trivial to others, and vice versa.